# Cannot boot up initially

Tags: boot, boot-issues, noobs, pi-3

I bought a new Raspberry Pi 3.  I purchased a specific power supply for it as well (CanaKit 5V 2.5A Raspberry Pi 3 Power Supply).  I then formatted my 8Gb microSD card according to [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/sdxc_formatting.md) instructions.  I did this on Windows 10.  Now, when I connect my Pi to the TV, there is no output whatsoever.  It is like there is no boot sequence at all.  All I see is this blue screen on my TV:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What LEDs light up on the Pi?

Comment: @DarthVader As you can see in the 2nd picture above, the green light and orange light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.  The NOOBS zip I downloaded from raspberrypi.org was incomplete.  It **ONLY** had the following files:

[image]

**Therefore**, I had to re-download the NOOBS files as a torrent.  And now my Raspberry Pi 3 boots up!